# Сортировка структуры по параметру

Tags: сортировка, структуры, c++

Уважаемые программисты, у меня возникла проблема с написанием программ. Суть проблемы: не понимаю, в чем ошибка в f3, выдает: [Error] invalid array assignment, ругается на buf, в который я хочу записать переменную типа char из структуры. И вторая проблема: мне нужно отсортировать структуру по номеру группы, но он просто заменяет, а не сортирует. Как отсортировать структуру, НЕ применяя sort или что-то в таком духе?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

const int N=3;
struct student {char fam[15];
    int kurs;
    char grup[3];
    float stip; };
void f1(student);

void f2(student parm[]);

void f3(student parm[]);

int main() { 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
int i; float maxs;
student stud[N];

//function 2
printf("\n rabota f2\n");
f2(stud);
getch();

maxs=0; 
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
if(stud[i].stip>maxs) maxs=stud[i].stip;
printf("\n stud - max stipendija %f rub ",maxs);
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
 if(stud[i].stip==maxs) printf ("\n%s",stud[i].fam);
getch();

//function f1
printf("\n rabota f1\n");
 for (i=0; i<N;i++) f1(stud[i]);
 getch();

//function f3
 printf("\n rabota f3\n");
 f3(stud);
 getch();

  }

 void f2(student parm[]){

 int i;
   for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
   printf("%d # Ñòóäåíò",i+1);
   printf("\nÔàìèëèÿ:"); cin>>parm[i].fam;
   printf("Êóðñ:"); cin>>parm[i].kurs;
   printf("Ãðóïïà:"); cin>>parm[i].grup;
   printf("Ñòèïåíäèÿ:"); cin>>parm[i].stip;
     }

    }
   void f1(student parm) {
    cout<<parm.fam<<" "<<parm.kurs<<" "<<parm.grup<<" "<<parm.stip<<"\n"; }

      void f3(student parm[]){
        int i,j=0, k;     // ñ÷åò÷èê öèêëîâ è òåêóùèé èíäåêñ ýëåìåíòà ìàññèâà
    char buf[3];
       cout<<"\nÑîðòèðîçêà ìàññèâà ìåòîäîì \"ïóçûðüêà\"\n";
       for(i=0;i<N;i++) cout<<parm[i].grup<<" ";
      for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) { j++;
      for (k =0; k < N-1; k++) {
      if (parm[k].grup < parm[k+1].grup) {// îáìåíÿåì ê-é è (ê+1)-é ýëåìåíòû
       buf= parm[k].grup; parm[k].grup = parm[k+1].grup ; parm[k+1].grup = buf; } }
        // îòëàäî÷íàÿ ïå÷àòü - ñîñòîÿíèå
           // ìàññèâà ïîñëå î÷åðåäíîãî öèêëà ñîðòèðîâêè
      cout<<"\n-----"<<j<<"-----";
      for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
      cout<<parm[k].grup<<" ";
     cout<<"\n";
    }

     printf("\n massiv otsortirovan\n");
     for (i=0; i<N;i++) f1(parm[i]);
     getch();
    }
```

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы забыли приложить код, телепатией, конечно, обладаем, но не до такой степени.

Comment: Вы правы! Исправила..

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

В языках типа C/C++ вы не можете копировать сложные штуки (типа массивов) простым присвоением. Ваш код

```
buf= parm[k].grup
```

пытается сделать именно это.

Поскольку вы пишете (судя по всему) на чистом C, вам стоит воспользоваться встроенным [копированием памяти](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```
memcpy(/*куда*/ buf, /*откуда*/ parm[k].grup, /*сколько*/ 3);
```

Почему не `strcpy`? Потому что у вас строки фиксированной длины, а значит, имеют право не оканчиваться на `\0`.

По поводу сортировки: это ж у вас пузырьковая сортировка, да? Сейчас ваш код обмена обменивает лишь группу, а вам-то надо обменять целого студента! Вам лучше всего написать отдельную вспомогательную функцию `swap(student* s1, student* s2)`, которая будет обменивать значения структур. И в нём обменивать не только группу, но и остальные поля. (Заодно текст программы станет более обозримым.)

Comment: @Хоббит, (маленькая подсказка для реализации `swap()`)

а вот  структуры (в отличие от массивов) можно копировать оператором присваивания (т.е. код swap() студентов будет почти таким же, как swap() двух чисел в массиве).

Comment: @avp: И правда! Хороший трюк, кстати. Я о нём совсем и забыл.

Comment: @avp, только если структуры - Plain Old Data :)

Comment: @smallFish: у C всё просто — POD или указатели. Указателей нету — можно копировать побитно. У C++ с этим, конечно, сложнее.

@avp: Раздумываю, почему в C есть синтаксис побитного копирования структур, а массивов нету. Наверное, потому, что массивы могут быть _очень_ длинными => простая операция выходит порядочно дорогой, что противоречит идеологии C.

Comment: @VladD, не думаю, что из-за длины.

IMHO это потому, что массивы в Си очень близки к указателям. Фактически везде, кроме той области, где массив определяется (под него отводится память), массив и указатель не различимы.

Поэтому операция копирования массива получается какой-то убогой, в одном месте ей можно воспользоваться, а во всех других -- нет.

Размер же, явно не помеха. Если массив (размер фиксирован, но не ограничен) является частью структуры, то он будет замечательно копироваться (естественно, вместе с остальными полями структуры).

--

POD -- ну, разумеется (другие просто не нужны).

Comment: Я сделала это! Просто после if заменять нужно всю структуру, а я заменяю отдельный элемент :)

Comment: @Хоббит: Точно! Так и надо. Вот видите, чему-то научились.

В C структуры можно копировать простым присваиванием, а массивы нельзя. Поэтому код и не компилировался.

Answer (score 0):

Bидимо, вы используете массив или ссылку "buf". Создайте цикл или функцию, которая обменяет 2 элемента в структуре. В си нельзя обменять два массива или две структуры местами напрямую. Сортировать данные внутри структуры можно так же, как и данные вне. Используйте [сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), которая вам больше понравится.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, как правильно записать buf. А насчет сортировки - этими способами он просто заменяет мне числа, а мне нужно, чтобы он по позиции структуру отсортировал. :((